# Shuffle questions along with their respective choices

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a quiz (using tkinter), and I want to randomly shuffle the questions I'll display, but because It's multiple choice, I've got to make sure **It's shuffled with the right choices**, otherwise, the questions and the choices won't make sense.

In order to accomplish this, I've wrote the following piece of code:

These are my choices:

```
q1 = ['up','in','out']
q2 = ['off', 'out', 'up']
q3 = ['got', 'get', 'down']
q4 = ['out', 'over', 'up']
q5 = ['up', 'under', 'down']
q6 = ['in', 'on', 'over']
q7 = ['down', 'over', 'up']
q8 = ['in', 'over', 'out']
```

, and the questions:

```
questions_list = ['Could you possibly put the rubbish  ___?',
                 'Something\'s cropped ___ at work',
                 'Perhaps we can ___ together then',
                 'He\'s hanging his jacked ___',
                 'She\'s tripped him ___',
                  'He\'s knocked him ___',
                 'He\'s doing his jacked ___',
                 'She\'s put her jumper inside ___']
```

Once they are defined in a list, I use them in a dictionary, like shown:

```
choices_dic = {'Could you possibly put the rubbish  ___?': q1,
             'Something\'s cropped ___ at work': q2,
             'Perhaps we can ___ together then': q3,
             'He\'s hanging his jacked ___': q4,
             'She\'s tripped him ___': q5,
              'He\'s knocked him ___': q6,
             'He\'s doing his jacked ___': q7,
             'She\'s put her jumper inside ___': q8}

shuffled = random.sample(questions_list,8)
```

I shuffled the questions using `sample`. Why? I'll add more than eight questions in order to have different questions every time I restart the quiz, or atleast some being different, but right now It doesn't matter. That's why I only have eight questions in `questions_list`

```
window = tk.Tk()
```

Since I've already defined the lists, I'll `label` the questions.

```
num1 = tk.IntVar()
num1.set(4) # I copied this eight times, you'll see why soon.

for i in range(1,9):
questions = tk.Label(window, text = shuffled[i - 1]).grid(column = 0, row = (3*i - 1), columnspan = 3, sticky = tk.W)
for x in range(3):
    options1 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num1, value = x)
    options1.grid(column = x, row = 3*i , sticky = tk.W)

    options2 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num2, value = x)
    options2.grid(column = x, row = 3*i, sticky = tk.W)

    options3 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num3, value = x)
    options3.grid(column = x, row = 3*i, sticky = tk.W)

    options4 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num4, value = x)
    options4.grid(column = x, row = 3*i, sticky = tk.W)

    options5 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num5, value = x)
    options5.grid(column = x, row = 3*i, sticky = tk.W)

    options6 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num6, value = x)
    options6.grid(column = x, row = 3*i, sticky = tk.W)

    options7 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num7, value = x)
    options7.grid(column = x, row = 3*i, sticky = tk.W)

    options8 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text = choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])], variable = num8, value = x)
    options8.grid(column = x, row = 3*i, sticky = tk.W)

window.mainloop()
```

This is messy and, of course, wrong. Before we get there, I would like just to clarify what `choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])]` does. You basically take a element from the `choices_dic` dictionary in the given order (check the range), and because it must be a string, I used `str()` method.

The code above is wrong because it does this:

[image: issue]

As you can see, when you select a radiobutton, you select all of the radiobuttons in its row. You can also take notice of how for each radiobutton in each row, there's a list that is labeled because of `choices_dic[str(shuffled[i-1])]`. Not what I intended.

So, indeed, I have another issue. How can I display each of the elements in `choices_dic` per radiobutton in all of the rows, that is, without displaying the whole list for each radiobutton three times as I showed in the image above?

I'm aware of what caused the issue, but I do not know how to solve it.

I hope this was enough for you to understand what I did.

EDIT:
It's been a while, I almost forgot I asked this question. My solution is:
[image: solution]
It pretty simple. With the above, you can create a class, or a function, to execute the code.

Comment: What is your actual question? What *specific* problem do you need help with?

Comment: @ekhumoro I want to display each question with its choices and, when I shuffle the questions, I shuffle their respective choices as well. Thus, If question number one is moved to where question number two is because of the shuffle, I also move questions one's chocies. I may not have been clear enough 'cause I showed other issues I came across with, but, anyway, I think I stated my goal in the first paragrahps.

Comment: `shuffled = random.sample(choices_dic.items(), 8)`

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you, but that's only part of my problem. That's why my question is tagged with tkinter. I'm trying to display the elements in that list for each of the three radiobuttons in each row without showing the entire list per radiobutton. I checked my post and yes, I didn't point out my other question for the same issue.

Comment: @Nameless Don't post your answer in the question's body instead add it as an answer.